# Timesliced Cassandra model for ad-hoc querying of UGC data

Tags: cassandra

Been experimenting with schema's for this for a couple of weeks now (with a few SO Q/As), and I'm still not happy with any of the final designs. Maybe someone can suggest something different.

I have a firehose of incoming logging data, in the format [timestamp, name, { custom_data }], where the data is a set of user defined key:value pairs inserted ad-hoc. There's a number of ways of storing this that are sane... however all the methods I have found fall down when querying.

The querying needs include properties of the custom_data. For example, one might need to query all events with custom data: { foo = bar } or { wibble = bar }. The data is moved on mass to a cluster for processing, and the bottleneck here is often data on the wire. The requirement is to move as small amount of data as possible. Typically events had 10 or so custom values of varying length, and a query would only need 2 or 3 of them. The impact of pulling 7 unused values is huge.

My experiments in schema have been as follows:

**Cassandra Map**

```
CREATE TABLE logs (
    action varchar,
    date_bucket ascii,
    action_time timeuuid,
    custom_data map<text, text>,
PRIMARY KEY ((action, date_bucket), action_time)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (action_time DESC)
```

This was the nicest way to get data in, and the cleanest schema. Inserts were fine.

Doesn't work because: Doing queries pulls back the entire map. There's no way to selectively query against the map and this results in too much data being on the wire.

**EAV Schema**

```
CREATE TABLE logs (
    action varchar,
    date_bucket ascii,
    action_time timeuuid,
    property varchar,
    value varchar,
PRIMARY KEY ((action, date_bucket), action_time, property)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (action_time DESC, property)
```

Somewhat traditional EAV type model.

Doesn't work because:

1) I couldn't find a way to query this in the needed manner. action_time is declared before property so if you do a select where property = 'foo' you will get "Bad Request: PRIMARY KEY part property cannot be restricted (preceding part action_time is either not restricted or by a non-EQ relation)"

2) The schema can be re-arranged to give property before action_time so the above query works. However, you can't query for a subset of properties anyway (property IN ...) as you will get Bad Request: PRIMARY KEY part property cannot be restricted by IN relation.

3) Even if you could get this to work, the result set will still be EAV so the data on the wire is not optimal. For each event the result would be [{timeid:property_1:value}...{timeid:property_n:value}] where as the optimal result would be {timeid:[property_1:value...property_n:value]}. Given that in many cases timeid is the same width as the property data, this is a big difference.

**Schema Mutations**

Well... this isn't pretty. This is an empty schema with no values.

```
CREATE TABLE logs (
    action varchar,
    date_bucket ascii,
    action_time timeuuid
    PRIMARY KEY ((action, date_bucket), action_time)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (action_time DESC)
```

Whenever a property is inserted the insert will be tried straight off using (a suitable encoded version of) the property name as the column name. If the column isn't there an ALTER TABLE statement is issued and the value is re-inserted.

It meets the query requirements however I am not confident this will scale particularly well. I think there would probably only be ~10k total property names, but lots of concurrent schema changes scare me.

**Something Else?**

I am looking for better ideas. Hopefully there are some out there. This doesn't seem like a particularly niche model to me.

I think I'm looking for something like wide rows *within* wide rows (if that makes sense)?

It might be that Cassandra is just not suited to this. I am open to this being an answer.